# allow client signin from auth0 access aws IoT

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, iot, auth0

I have been working on accessing the aws IoT from JS(webapp). I am using Auth0 for user login. I've also setup AWS delegation in Auth0. I have appended the following rule in Auth0.

```
role:arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:role/access-to-iot-per-user
principal:arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:saml-provider/auth0-provider
```

On IAM console, I've attached the following policy to the given role above

AWSIoTDataAccess

As per my basic understanding, the delegation token now should allow us to connect to the IoT in aws in my account but I am getting 403 forbidden error while connecting. Am I doing anything wrong?

`